# how to invoke python script in c++ code?

Tags: python, c++

in my `C++` application, I want to invoke a `Python` script to do some processing works. I have searched in Google and found there are two ways to do this:

```
    (1). use the `system` command. Just like this, `system('python myscript.py');`
    (2). use the `PyRun_SimpleString("execfile('myscript.py')");`
```

I want to ask that, which way is better and is there any better way to do this work?

Thanks.

Comment: Depends on what you consider _is better_ ...

Comment: Use popen() as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c/478960#478960)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to ask that, which way is better and is there any better way to do this work?

You should notice that the python engine is written in C and therefore provides a [native C-API](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/). This allows you to interact more directly with python code, by means of calling functions and using python objects.

If you want to integrate it from C++ code without hassling with the C-API, there's the excellent and easy to use [boost::python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/) library.

Answer (score 1):

I think that boost provides libraries to do that. But I never used them.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/